# How to Replicate Vergil's Judgement cut end Effect in Blender?

Tags: materials, effects

I'm fairly new to Blender so I don't know a whole lot. I'm in the process of working on an animation and wanted to include an effect similar to Vergil's Judgement Cut from Devil May Cry 5, where everything looks split like a shattered glass mirror. I have no idea how to go about achieving this effect.

Currently, I've attempted to place multiple cubes over a model with materials that have 1.0 transmission, 0 roughness, and screen space refraction turned on. The result isn't that great. I'd appreciate any advice one has to offer as to what I can do to create the effect I'm after. Thank you for your time.

I'll link a video to help demonstrate the effect I'm looking to replicate: [Devil May Cry 5 - Vergil Motivated Combo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEZON93hV-s&t=28s)

Here is a picture of the specific effect I'm attempting to achieve from the linked video as advised. I'm trying to make it where it'll look like everything in my scene is split apart by glass. Unfortunately I don't know how to describe the desired result any better than that.

[image: Judgement Cut Effect]

Comment: Sharing some screenshots of what you have already and describing the effect you are after and your specific scene might help you get answers. Now it's not very clear what you are talking about. It's hard to imagine what you want your result to be.

Comment: It seems like it could also be achieved with some masking and position change in the compositor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could surround your object (or scene) with a large cube, and give it a shader like this - it's just a Voronoi Texture "warping" the refraction of the cube. It only works in Cycles, though, and there are un avoidable black "chunks" that show up in certain areas depending on the values fed to the IOR (as seen at the top in the screenshot). It may take some tweaking, but given the scene example video, you may be able to incorporate the "black spots" into the background in a way that is not obvious or unpleasant.

[image: GlassBroke]